# IntelliJ: importing Android project from Eclipse leads to duplicate class error

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to switch from doing my Android development in Eclipse to using IntelliJ instead. Right now I'm trying to import one of my open source projects. It consists of the main application project, HackerNews (which has a number of jar dependencies, including the support library). It also depends on two library projects I use to share code between apps: DatabaseUtils (which has no dependencies) and HoloTheme (which also depends on the support library).

All three projects are in the same folder and work fine in Eclipse. However, when I try to build the project with IntelliJ, I get couple of errors like this:

`java: /Users/matthewbbishop/Library/Caches/IdeaIC12/compile-server/github-clean-install_673da148/targets/java-production/HoloTheme/android/generated_sources/build_config/com/airlocksoftware/holo/BuildConfig.java:4: duplicate class: com.airlocksoftware.holo.BuildConfig`

and

`java: /Users/matthewbbishop/Library/Caches/IdeaIC12/compile-server/github-clean-install_673da148/targets/java-production/HoloTheme/android/generated_sources/aapt/com/airlocksoftware/holo/R.java:10: duplicate class: com.airlocksoftware.holo.R`

I've already had to switch the scope of the support libary in the HoloTheme project to provided to fix another error. Here are the current state of the dependencies tabs for the three projects (or I guess they're called modules in IntelliJ?)

Any ideas on what the problem is? Or if you need more info please let me know! Thanks!

EDIT: image embedding isn't working for some reason. See [this album on imgur instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMYeI.png)

Comment: Your image links are not operable...

Comment: Weird, they show up in the preview. Anyway, I just added a link to the images instead.

Comment: You have duplicate dependencies (`lib`, `holotheme` added as both library and module, etc). Make sure no dependency is duplicated, use module dependencies and Export option for the libraries to be available to the other modules, [refer to help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: @CrazyCoder You just saved my morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed it: by unmarking the module as "Sources Root".
If your folder structure looks like the first preview (like mine):

[image] which became -> [image]

Right click the module in question: yields this context menu

[image]